# Approximation Set Covering Problem

Tags: approximation

I am studying approximation Set Covering problem, from "Introduction to Algorithms by Thomas H. Cormen" book. What I cannot understand is why they use harmonic numbers to the proof? What harmonic numbers have to do with this?? I am totally confused..

Comment: Did you understand the simpler approximation?  What _do_ you understand?

Comment: They come up since they happen to bound the approximation ratio.